# ReflectionException: Class does not exist

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I'm running into this error when I tried to run the composer

```
{
    "name": "zepluf/standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"ZePLUF Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": ">=2.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": ">=2.1",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web"
    }
}
```

It seems like somehow an empty classname is passed in, but I'm not so sure how to do debug back trace to locate where it is.

```
D:\Programming\xampp\htdocs\demo\zepluf>composer update --verbose
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files



  [ReflectionException]
  Class  does not exist



Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handl
ing the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception



  [RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the ""cache:clear --no-warmup"" command.



Exception trace:
 () at D:\Programming\xampp\htdocs\demo\zepluf\vendor\sensio\distribution-bundle
\Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler.php:137
 Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::executeCommand() at D:
\Programming\xampp\htdocs\demo\zepluf\vendor\sensio\distribution-bundle\Sensio\B
undle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler.php:48
 Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache() at phar:/
/C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Script/EventDispatcher.p
hp:122
 Composer\Script\EventDispatcher->executeEventPhpScript() at phar://C:/ProgramDa
ta/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Script/EventDispatcher.php:101
 Composer\Script\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer
/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Script/EventDispatcher.php:74
 Composer\Script\EventDispatcher->dispatchCommandEvent() at phar://C:/ProgramDat
a/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:237
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/s
rc/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:82
 Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin
/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.
php:238
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Compo
ser/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Applicati
on.php:193
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Compose
r/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:101
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/com
poser.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:106
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/
bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:74
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/compo
ser.phar/bin/composer:37
 require() at C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin\composer.phar:15


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-custom-instal
lers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [
packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

Comment: Could you run it again with --verbose and see if you get a backtrace? Maybe paste your entire output?

Comment: thank you for looking into it, I ran again and posted the output in the question

Comment: Ah the exception is in the script itself so hard to say.. Maybe try removing your symfony cache (app/cache/*) by hand just in case there is some bad code in there that triggers this error maybe?

Comment: I always have this error before the "cache-warmup". It has something to do with permissions on my Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Well maybe you should just remove the clearCache line from post-update-cmd and post-install-cmd if it plain doesn't work for you.

Comment: yes if I remove those 2 lines, 1. I still have the error"[ReflectionException] Class  does not exist" 2. I get rid of the error with cache 3. I get a new error with installAssets

Comment: It seems like the error was because I attempted to retrieve a service inside a dependency compiler pass. I wonder what is another solution because I do need to access that service there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the error was because I attempted to retrieve a service inside a dependency compiler pass. I rewrote my code to avoid having to retrieve service from there.

Comment: Can you offer a bit more explanation?

Comment: It's too long ago and I cannot recall this anymore. However, it seems like I was trying to get a service inside a Compiler Pass class, and since this server is not ready yet it resulted in the error posted.