# Access a service from within the compiler pass

Tags: symfony

I'm having this piece of code inside my bundle

```
class MyPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->get("plugin")->loadServices($container);
    }
}
```

When I run the app normally via the web browser, everything seems fine. However, if I run the composer with

```
"post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
```

It seems like trying to get the service from within the compiler class will return the error ReflectionException: Class  does not exist. Is there anyway to resolve this?

(The service is used to register a list of custom plugins' services, it has to be run somewhere here in the compiler pass to allow SF2 to cache it)

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace please ?

Comment: Hi, When I run "composer update --verbose" I get this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947831/reflectionexception-class-does-not-exist#comment19238946_13947831 Not sure if I can somehow get a more detailed trace for you.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to rewrite my code to not rely on getting service from within the compiler pass.